# grails find() using 3 fields/columns (i.e. a find with multiple columns)

Tags: grails

I'm a little confused about the Grails HQL documentation.  Say I have a domain class with 3 fields,

```
class Example {
   String a 
   String b
   String c
 }
```

and I want to do the equivalent of an Example.findByAAndBAndC(), can you show me the line of code that I'd use to set that up and pass in the 3 parameters?  Note the documentation says, one can at most use two fields for the findBy.  I need to do 3 fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use dynamic finders if you have more than 2 predicates. Use a criteria query instead:

```
def results = Example.withCriteria {
  eq('a', 'some-a')
  eq('b', 'some-b')
  eq('c', 'some-c')
}
```

### Update

By default, the predicates are combined using AND, if you want OR instead use:

```
def results = Example.withCriteria {
  or {
    eq('a', 'some-a')
    eq('b', 'some-b')
    eq('c', 'some-c')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Don, is this always an AND combination? -- i.e. your syntax?  Just as an example, could you also show an OR combination

Answer (score 6):

i use in my project:

```
Example.findAllByAIlikeAndBIlikeAndCIlike("${a}%","${b}%","${c}%",[max:5, offset:0, sort:"a", order:"asc"])
```

and it works!

Comment: This is only supported from Grails 2 onwards.

Answer (score 4):

Ray,

There are a few ways to "find" objects.

findWhere:

```
Example.findWhere(a:"Hello", B:"World")
Example.findByAandB("a value", "b value)
```

---

I'd suggest you to have a good read at:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/ 
and
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.4.2%20Criteria

The documentation is quite good and has several examples.

Comment: Guilherme, thanks for providing this second documentation.  However, I don't feel you understood my question.  Was it confusing?  I want to simply do a find on 3 fields, instead of the default "2" that Grails gives you, with the findField1AndField2()

Comment: Nevermind, I think you did answer the question in the first part!  I can simply do an Example.findWhere(a:"Hello", b:"World", c:"hi"), unless I misunderstood you?